# What is meant by "double speed" in dense coding protocol?

Tags: entanglement, superdense-coding

As mentioned [in this article](https://algassert.com/quantum/2014/05/03/Storing-Bandwidth-with-Superdense-Coding.html), "*This (densecoding) lets you transmit at double speed until the pre-delivered qubits run out*." What is meant by *double speed* here?

Answer (score 2):

Dense coding lets you send two classical bits for every qubit you transmit, assuming the two parties already share enough entanglement. This two for one trade-off is what's being called "double speed".